# Structure as a class member in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible  a structure as a class member in objective C? If yes how can I assign values to that structure from another class?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. You either just expose the structure as a property (in which case you have to set/get the whole thing) or you write custom accessors that walk into the fields of the strucutre.

For a concrete example, CGRect is a structure (though it is hidden by a typdef), which means the frame property of UIView get and set a structure.

In other words:

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480); //CGRect is a struct
myView.frame = myFrmae; //Setting a struct
```

Comment: Can you explain a little detail. becoz i am new to C.

Comment: Is there away to prevent doing something like the following which won't work? `myView.frame.origin.x = 4;`

Answer (score 1):

You just use dot notation to assign and access the values. You can also use `->` if you have a pointer to a struct.

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  double b;
} SomeType;

// Define some class which uses SomeType
SomeType myVar;

myVar.a = 1;
myVar.b = 1.0;

SomeType* myPtr = &myVar;

NSLog (@"%i", myPtr->a);

// This works...
SomeType mySecondVar = myVar;

// But you have to be careful in cases where you have pointers rather than values.
// So this wouldn't work if either element was a C string or an array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and there is an easy way to access that struct using Objective-C 2.0 Properties.  Consider the following struct from Stephens post.

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  double b;
} SomeType;
```

In your .h file you would declare the member in your @interface

```
@interface AClass : NSObject{
  SomeType member;
}

@property SomeType member;
@end
```

Remember that if you choose to go with pointers here you will need to manage your own memory.

And in your @implementation (your .m file) don't forget add a @synthesize

```
@implementation AClass
@synthesize member;
@end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `assign` is the default behavior of synthesized properties, and the runtime is smart enough to know not to retain a struct.  It can easily look at its type encoding and see that it's not an Objective-C object.