# Cocoa Objective-c Property C structure assign fails

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, structure

I want to change the variable value which is a member of a structure of another class.
But the value is not getting changed.

Here is the code.

```
//Structure..

typedef struct {
    int a;
    double b;
} SomeType;


//Class which has the structure as member..
@interface Test2 : NSObject {
    // Define some class which uses SomeType
    SomeType member;

}

@property SomeType member;

@end


@implementation Test2

@synthesize member;

@end


//Tester file, here value is changed..
@implementation TesstAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 

    Test2 *t = [[Test2 alloc]init];

    t.member.a = 10;
//After this the value still shows 0

}

@end
```

I tried out with the below link.

[Structure as a class member in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687144/structure-as-a-class-member-in-objective-c)

Regards,
Dhana.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To make a change to your 'member' instance variable, you need to set it in its entirety.  You should do something like:

```
SomeType mem = t.member;
mem.a = 10;
t.member = mem;
```

The problem is that `t.member` is being used as a "getter" (since it's not immediately followed by an '='), so `t.member.a = 10;` is the same as `[t member].a = 10;`

That won't accomplish anything, because `[t member]` returns a struct, which is an "r-value", ie. a value that's only valid for use on the right-hand side of an assignment.  It has a value, but it's meaningless to try to change that value.

Basically, `t.member` is returning a copy of your 'member' struct.  You're then immediately modifying that copy, and at the end of the method that copy is discarded.

Comment: Oh, `t.member.a` is just fine for _reading_ the value of `member.a`.  It's exactly the same as `[t member].a`.

Comment: Do you know what that sound is, highness? Those are the shrieking C# developers. If you don't believe me, just wait. They always grow louder when they're about to use dot notation in Objective-C! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tfo3nEZHNLk

Comment: @sb. why `t.member` is returning a copy of the struct?

Comment: So.. how efficient is this assignment if your struct contains thousands of primitives and you just change one?

Comment: @quantumpotato Not extremely efficient since the whole structure has to be copied on the stack, but if you really have a struct that contains a thousand fields efficiency is probably the least of your concerns. In that case you could have your method return a pointer to the struct and assign it directly with `[t member]->a = 10`.

Answer (score 4):

Make a pointer to your struct instead, then just dereference it when you want to change a part of it.

Example:

```
struct myStruct {
    int a,
        b;
};

@interface myClass : NSObject {
myStruct *testStruct;
}

@property myStruct *testStruct;
```

Then to change a part of myStruct just do `myClassObject.testStruct->a = 55;`

Answer (score 1):

Change the synthesize line to:

`@synthesize member = _member;`

Then you can assign values in one line of code:

`_member.a = 10;`