# cocos2d: Why can't I change a scaled node's position?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I think I'm just understanding scaling/positioning nodes/layers incorrectly. I'm setting up my node like this (node class is derived from `CCNode`):

```
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        // Create parallax background node.
        background = [BackgroundNode node];
        [self addChild:background z:0];

        // Create foreground node.
        foreground = [ForegroundLayer node];
        [self addChild:foreground z:0];

        self.position.y = 500.0f;
        self.scaleX = 1.5f;
        self.scaleY = 1.5f;
    }

    return self;
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I set the `self.position.y` to - the scaled node is **always** displayed as though it was positioned in the bottom-left of the screen. I've tried playing around with `anchorPoint` as well, but it doesn't really seem to change anything.

The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to be able to pan vertically when I'm zoomed in - this doesn't seem to really be the right way to accomplish it, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.position.y = 500.0f;
```

doesn't work. It should be

```
self.position = ccp(self.position.x, 500.0f);
```

Please refer to "[Cocoa Objective-c Property C structure assign fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425213/629118)".