# Monotouch Frame dimensions can't be set directly?

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

Editing UI Frame properties directly don't seem to work.

i.e.

```
scrollView.ContentSize.Width = 100;
```

doesn't work but

```
RectangleF scrollFrame = ScrollView.Frame;
scrollFrame.Width = width * pageCount;
ScrollView.ContentSize = scrollFrame.Size;
```

does! Why is this? Isn't Monotouch supposed to protect
against arcane programming styles?

Comment: I have a feeling this will be something to do with iOS rather Monotouch...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basic C# behavior.

The ContentSize property is a SizeF which is a struct (=value type) and not a class (=reference type).

Calling

```
scrollView.ContentSize.Width = 100;
```

does not work because you are setting a value on a property of a copied object.

Calling

```
scrollFrame.Width = width * pageCount;
```

works because although RectangleF is also a struct, you are setting a value on the actual object.

Likewise,

```
ScrollView.ContentSize = scrollFrame.Size;
```

creates a copy, but sets a new object after the '=' and works correctly.

Comment: found here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425213/cocoa-objective-c-property-c-structure-assign-fails