# MonoTouch: How to change control's location at runtime?

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios

I want to change the location of an UIImageView at runtime. In IB, I can change X coordinate to relocate it. So, I tried this code:

```
imageView.Frame.X = 25;
```

But it doesn't have any effect. Why? I have the same problem for other controls as well. How to make it work?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976717/monotouch-frame-dimensions-cant-be-set-directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Frame property is a value type, this means that if you do:

```
imageView.Frame.X = 25
```

what you are actually doing is:

```
var temp = imageView.Frame;
temp.X = 25;
```

The value never reaches the imageView.   With value types, you have to assign a fully constructed type, so for example:

var current = imageView.Frame;
current.X = 25;
imageView.Frame = current;

Answer (score 0):

The Frame property is a value type, this means that if you do:

imageView.Frame.X = 25

what you are actually doing is:

var temp = imageView.Frame;
temp.X = 25;

The value never reaches the imageView.   With value types, you have to assign a fully constructed type, so for example:

var current = imageView.Frame;
current.X = 25;
imageView.Frame = current;

Answer (score 0):

// The Code is quite simple and self explanatory

> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

```
    self.myimageView.frame = CGRectMake(140, 70, 140, 128);


});
```

By using >dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ I made the code to run in the main queue, not in the background.