# A more elegant way to change a single element in a struct in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there a more elegant way to change a single element in a View.Frame struct in Xamarin/C# without using one of the following patterns?

```
var frame = View.Frame;
frame.Y = 123;
View.Frame = frame;
```

or

```
View.Frame = new RectangleF(View.Frame.X, 123, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);
```

Simply changing the element like this: `View.Frame.Y = 123;` doesn't have any effect.  Only once the entire Frame struct is reassigned does it take effect.

Comment: It probably doesn't have any effect because `View.Frame` is probably a property. When you access it, it returns a _copy_ of the Frame because it's a value type. I personally prefer your first style; seems a bit more explicit about what your intent is regarding what aspects are changing. (not to mention it avoids hitting the `Frame` property getter 3 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a few minutes and tried to come up with something, but because the Frame is a struct it doesn't look there is a more elegant way:

[MonoTouch: How to change control's location at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499394/monotouch-how-to-change-controls-location-at-runtime)

One thing you could possibly do is create a static utility class like this that you could reuse:

```
public static class FrameUtil{
     public RectangleF UpdateX(RectangleF frame, float newX){
          var tempFrame = frame;
          tempFrame.x = newX;
          return tempFrame;
     }
}
```

Comment: `View.Frame = new RectangleF(View.Frame.X, 123, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);`

is now:

`View.Frame = FrameHelper.X(View.Frame, 123);`

This is a little better.  I've already started using it.  Thanks.